# Two dimensional Varray

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

**How to create a 2D varray in Oracle??**

It can be a string array or an integer or both.

Comment: Declare a varray type and then use this type as a base for another varray type

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I included them in my descriptions. Please check out this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to 2D varray like 2D matrix

Comment: Just to comment, varrays are mostly useful as database table columns. In PL/SQL programming where you just want an array type to use within some code, nested table collections are normally a better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a 2-dimensional `VARRAY`. You can either:

1. Create a `VARRAY` containing a `VARRAY`:

   ```sql
   CREATE TYPE numbers_column AS VARRAY(3) OF NUMBER;
   CREATE TYPE numbers_matrix AS VARRAY(3) OF numbers_column;

   SELECT numbers_matrix(
            numbers_column(1,4,7),
            numbers_column(2,5,8),
            numbers_column(3,6,9),
          )
   FROM   DUAL;
   ```
2. Use a 1-dimensional `VARRAY` containing MxN items and when you want to get the item at position (x,y) then use arithmetic to calculate the position and get the `x+(y-1)*M`<sup>th</sup> element:

   ```sql
   CREATE TYPE numbers_matrix AS VARRAY(9) OF NUMBER;

   SELECT numbers_matrix(
            1,2,3,
            4,5,6,
            7,8,9
          )
   FROM   DUAL;
   ```

Comment: x+(y-1)*Mth please clarify this formula.

Comment: @SuyogMate If you have a 5x6 matrix then the the first row will have indexes 1..5, the second row indexes 6..10, the third row 11-15, etc. So if you want the element in position (2,3) then you want the 2nd column in the 3rd row which would be `2+(3-1)*5 = 12`th item. As stated in the answer, in general for a matrix with size `MxN` when you want the element in position `(x,y)` then you want the `x+(y-1)*M`th element in the one-dimensional array representing the 2D matrix.